# Basis Density Estimator and Information Channel Capacity

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, information-theory, density-function

Suppose that I would like to estimate the distribution $P$ with pdf $p$ over $[0,1]$ from the data $\{X_1,\cdots, X_T\}$, $X_i \sim_{iid} P$ using the basis estimator:
\begin{equation*}
\hat{p}_M(x) := \sum_{i=0}^M\hat{\theta}_i\phi_i(x), \quad \text{where} \quad \hat{\theta}_i := \frac{1}{T}\sum_{j=1}^T\phi_i(X_j).
\end{equation*}
Where $\{\phi_0,\phi_1,\phi_2, \cdots\}$ is a complete orthonormal $L^2[0,1]$ basis. For example, let's take the trigonometric basis for simplicity: $\phi_0(x) = 1, \phi_{2j}(x) = \sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi j x), \phi_{2j+1}(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi j x)$, for $j=1,2,3,\cdots$.
I can adjust $M$ as a hyperparameter of this estimator. If I set $M = 0$, then it looks like I use none of the data $\{X_1,\cdots,X_T\}$, and if I set $M = \infty$ then $\hat{p}_{M} \rightarrow_{L^2} p$ as $T\rightarrow \infty$.

**May I think of $\hat{p}_0(x)$ as my prior knowledge about the random variable $X$ and $\hat{p}_M(x)$ as my knowledge after observing the data $\{X_1,\cdots, X_T\}$ given my limited information process capacity which is controlled by $M$?**

**If so, is there any relationship between $M$ and the channel capacity in information theory?**

i.e. the channel capacity $C$ is the upper bound on the mutual information:
\begin{equation*}
I(X;\{X_i\}) := -\int_{[0,1]}\hat{p}_0(x)\log \hat{p}_0(x)dx + \mathbb{E}_{\text{data}}\left[\int_{[0,1]}\hat{p}_M(x)\log \hat{p}_M(x)dx\right]
\end{equation*}
where the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{\text{data}}$ is taken over all the data $\{X_1,\cdots, X_T\}$ distributed with the pdf $\prod_{i=1}^Tp(X_i)$. This should measure how much information is expected to be processed.

Comment: I don't see how you're attaching $M$ with the notion of information: the information you're gaining about the underlying laws is coming from the $X_i$s, so it's driven by $T$ rather than $M$. Also note that it is very untrue that as $M \to \infty, \hat{p}_M \to p$ (in any sense, really). In fact, in order to get decent behaviour in the worst case, it is important to tune $M$ to grow in a particular way with $T$ - otherwise you'd end up strongly overfitting to the data (and your estimate would start looking like the empirical law over the data).

Comment: Finally, it is not even meaningful to write $I(X;\{X_i\}):$ what is $X$? What are the joint laws?  _If_ you have a prior distribution over $P$ (which is not so simple over spaces like $L^2$), then you can meaningfully write things like $I(P;\{X_i\{)$ (since $P$ would then at least be a random object).

Comment: (Btw, you don't even need to go to $L^2$ to see these things: the same issues will pop up even when doing density estimation over a finite alphabet. Maybe work things out there to figure out exactly what you're trying to say, and whether it at least makes sense within the language you're trying to use)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited, what I meant was $\hat{p}_{\infty}\rightarrow p$ in $L^2$ as $T\rightarrow \infty$. I'm still learning and I apologize for my careless mistakes. 
Your point about how we need to tune $M$ to grow with $T$ is actually what I'm interested in. Suppose that I need $M = O(T^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha > 0$ to minimizes the expected MSE between $\hat{p}_M$ and $p$, can I get a similar statement in terms of $C$? e.g. requires that $C = O(T^{\beta})$ for some $\beta > 0$?

Comment: I think I understand your concern about $I(X;\{X_i\})$ that a measure on the space of distribution $P$ is needed. But is it alright to just fix a $P$, or consider $P$ satisfying some properties. e.g. if we consider the set of $P$ satisfying $\int |p''|dx < const$, then I believe we can show that it is optimal to tune $M^* = O(T^{1/5})$.

Comment: Another thing I also concern about is if we are using some basis such as trigonometric basis, then $\hat{p}_M$ may not be positive everywhere on $[0,1]$ (so $\log \hat{p}_M$ is not meaningful). Perhaps it is better to consider the bound in KDE bandwidth $h$ as a function of $T$. In that case, it is equivalent to set a bound in terms of the channel capacity $C = O(T^\beta)$ for some $\beta > 0$?